# wait until condition on selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

what will be code in `selenium webdriver` for **wait.until(---code here)**
on any **element by id** value change.
like-

`wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("")));`

I want to wait on element value which is change after click on webpage.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to wait for a **specific element** then u can go with **explicit wait**.
Try the below code, if it's not able to find that element then increase the wait time.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("")));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait till there appears some value on the element after clicking then go for one of the methods like

```
ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementXXXX(locator, text)
```

This will wait until certain expected text appears on the element

Answer (score 0):

This Method takes the argument element as value for ID and Timeout in Second.

```
public WebElement explicitWaitForElement(String element, long timeout) {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        WebElement ele = null;
        try {
            ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .presenceOfElementLocated(By
                            .id(element)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //exception
        }
        return ele;
    }
```